# Codeigniter image lib not resizing multiple images at once

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to resize multiple images at once in my foreach loop but does not do it. It only resizes some of them per page.

> Question how can I make sure it resizes the multiple images at once in my foreach loop on index()

As you can see it only resizes some of them the filemanager code is run/loaded ajax

[image]

```
<?php

class Filemanager extends MX_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('pagination');

    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['resize_error'] ='';

        $input_get_directory = $this->input->get('directory');
        $input_get_page = $this->input->get('page');
        $input_get_filter = $this->input->get('filter_name');
        $input_get_target = $this->input->get('target');
        $input_get_thumb = $this->input->get('thumb');

        if (isset($input_get_filter)) {
            $filter_name = $input_get_filter;
        } else {
            $filter_name = null;
        }

        // Make sure we have the correct directory
        if (isset($input_get_directory)) {

            $directory = FCPATH . 'image/catalog/' . $input_get_directory;

        } else {

            // Do not add extra tralier slash at end /
            $directory = FCPATH . 'image/catalog';
        }

        if (isset($input_get_page)) {
            $page = $input_get_page;
        } else {
            $page = 1;
        }

        $data['images'] = array();

        // Get directories
        $directories = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);

        if (!$directories) {
            $directories = array();
        }

        // Get files
        $files = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif,JPG,JPEG,PNG,GIF}', GLOB_BRACE);

        if (!$files) {
            $files = array();
        }

        // Merge directories and files
        $images = array_merge($directories, $files);

        // Get total number of files and directories
        $image_total = count($images);

        $per_page = 8;
        $segment = $this->input->get('per_page');
        $segment += $per_page;

        foreach ($images as $key => $image) {

            if ($key < $segment && $key >= $segment - $per_page) {

                $name = str_split(basename($image), 18);

                if (is_dir($image)) {

                    $url = '';

                    if (isset($input_get_target)) {
                        $url .= '&target=' . $input_get_target;
                    }

                    if (isset($input_get_thumb)) {
                        $url .= '&thumb=' . $input_get_thumb;
                    }

                    $data['images'][] = array(
                        'thumb' => '',
                        'name' => implode(' ', $name),
                        'type' => 'directory',
                        'path' => utf8_substr($image, utf8_strlen(FCPATH . 'image/')),
                        'href' => site_url('admin/common/filemanager') . '/?&directory=' . utf8_substr($image, utf8_strlen(FCPATH . 'image/' . 'catalog/')) . $url
                    );

                } elseif (is_file($image)) {

                // Resize function here

                $data['images'][] = array(
                        'thumb' => $this->resize($image),
                        'name' => implode(' ', $name),
                        'type' => 'image',
                        'test' => '',
                        'path' => utf8_substr($image, utf8_strlen(FCPATH . 'image/')),
                        'href' => base_url() . 'image/' . utf8_substr($image, utf8_strlen(FCPATH . 'image/'))
                    );
                }
            }
        }


        $this->load->view('common/filemanager_view', $data);
    }

    public function resize($filename) {
        $this->load->library('image_lib');

        $width = 100;
        $height = 100;

        $old_filename = substr($filename, strlen(FCPATH . 'image/'));

        $extension = pathinfo($old_filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        $new_image = substr($old_filename, 0, strrpos($old_filename, '.')) . '-' . $width . 'x' . $height . '.' . $extension;

        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = $filename;
        $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
        $config['width'] = $width;
        $config['height'] = $height;
        $config['new_image'] = FCPATH . 'image/cache/' . $new_image;

        $this->image_lib->clear();        
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();

        return base_url('image/cache/') . $new_image;
    }
}
```

This function below is called in the foreach loop on index

```
public function resize($filename) {
    $this->load->library('image_lib');

    $width = 100;
    $height = 100;

    $old_filename = substr($filename, strlen(FCPATH . 'image/'));

    $extension = pathinfo($old_filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    $new_image = substr($old_filename, 0, strrpos($old_filename, '.')) . '-' . $width . 'x' . $height . '.' . $extension;

    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] = $filename;
    $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
    $config['width'] = $width;
    $config['height'] = $height;
    $config['new_image'] = FCPATH . 'image/cache/' . $new_image;

    $this->image_lib->clear();        
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();

    return base_url('image/cache/') . $new_image;
}
```

Just the view for any one who wants it

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <div class="btn-toolbar mb-3" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
            <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="First group">
            <a class="btn btn-dark" href="<?php echo $parent;?>" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="<?php echo $button_parent; ?>" id="button-parent" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-level-up"></i></a> 
            <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="<?php echo $button_upload; ?>" id="button-upload" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i></button>
            <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="<?php echo $button_folder; ?>" id="button-folder" class="btn btn-dark"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i></button>
            <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"  title="<?php echo $button_delete; ?>" id="button-delete" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
            </div>

            <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for..." aria-label="Search for...">
            </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-header justify-content-center">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
        </ol>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">

        <!--
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">

            <a href="<?php echo $refresh;?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_refresh; ?>" id="button-refresh" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></a>



        </div>
      </div>

      -->

      <?php foreach (array_chunk($images, 4) as $image) { ?>
      <div class="row">
        <?php foreach ($image as $image) { ?>
        <div class="col-sm-3 text-center">
          <?php if ($image['type'] == 'directory') { ?>
          <div class="text-center"><a href="<?php echo $image['href']; ?>" class="directory" style="vertical-align: middle;"><i class="fa fa-folder fa-5x"></i></a></div>
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="path[]" value="<?php echo $image['path']; ?>" />
            <?php echo $image['name']; ?></label>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php if ($image['type'] == 'image') { ?>
          <a href="<?php echo $image['href']; ?>" class="thumbnail">
          <?php echo $image['thumb']; ?></a>
          <label>
            <input type="hidden" name="cache[]" value="<?php echo $image['cache']; ?>" />
            <input type="checkbox" name="path[]" value="<?php echo $image['path']; ?>" />
            <?php echo $image['name']; ?></label>
          <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer  justify-content-center">
        <?php echo $pagination; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('a.thumbnail').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    <?php if ($thumb) { ?>
    $('#<?php echo $thumb; ?>').find('img').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if ($target) { ?>

    $('#<?php echo $target; ?>').attr('value', $(this).parent().find('input').attr('value'));
    <?php } else { ?>

    var range, sel = document.getSelection(); 

    if (sel.rangeCount) { 
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = $(this).attr('href');

        range = sel.getRangeAt(0); 
        range.insertNode(img); 
    }
    <?php } ?>

    $('#modal-image').modal('hide');
});

$('a.directory').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#modal-image').load($(this).attr('href'));
});

$('.pagination a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#modal-image').load($(this).attr('href'));
});

$('.breadcrumb-item a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#modal-image').load($(this).attr('href'));
});


$('#button-parent').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#modal-image').load($(this).attr('href'));
});

$('#button-refresh').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#modal-image').load($(this).attr('href'));
});

$('input[name=\'search\']').on('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $('#button-search').trigger('click');
    }
});

$('#button-search').on('click', function(e) {
    var url = 'admin/common/filemanager?&directory=<?php echo $directory; ?>';

    var filter_name = $('input[name=\'search\']').val();

    if (filter_name) {
        url += '&filter_name=' + encodeURIComponent(filter_name);
    }

    <?php if ($thumb) { ?>
    url += '&thumb=' + '<?php echo $thumb; ?>';
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if ($target) { ?>
    url += '?target=' + '<?php echo $target; ?>';
    <?php } ?>

    $('#modal-image').load(url);
});
//--></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('#button-upload').on('click', function() {
    $('#form-upload').remove();

    $('body').prepend('<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-upload" style="display: none;"><input type="file" name="file" value="" /></form>');

    $('#form-upload input[name=\'file\']').trigger('click');

    if (typeof timer != 'undefined') {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }

    timer = setInterval(function() {
        if ($('#form-upload input[name=\'file\']').val() != '') {
            clearInterval(timer);

            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo base_url('admin/common/filemanager/upload?');?>directory=<?php echo $directory; ?>',
                type: 'post',       
                dataType: 'json',
                data: new FormData($('#form-upload')[0]),
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,     
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('#button-upload i').replaceWith('<i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i>');
                    $('#button-upload').prop('disabled', true);
                },
                complete: function() {
                    $('#button-upload i').replaceWith('<i class="fa fa-upload"></i>');
                    $('#button-upload').prop('disabled', false);
                },
                success: function(json) {
                    if (json['error']) {
                        alert(json['error']);
                    }

                    if (json['success']) {
                        alert(json['success']);

                        $('#button-refresh').trigger('click');
                    }
                },          
                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
                }
            }); 
        }
    }, 500);
});

$('#button-folder').popover({
    html: true,
    placement: 'bottom',
    trigger: 'click',
    title: 'New Folder',
    content: function() {
        html  = '<div class="input-group">';
        html += '  <input type="text" name="folder" value="" placeholder="New Folder" class="form-control">';
        html += '  <span class="input-group-btn"><button type="button" title="" id="button-create" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button></span>';
        html += '</div>';

        return html;    
    }
});

$('#button-folder').on('shown.bs.popover', function() {
    $('#button-create').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'admin/common/filemanager/folder?directory=<?php echo $directory; ?>',
            type: 'post',       
            dataType: 'json',
            data: 'folder=' + encodeURIComponent($('input[name=\'folder\']').val()),
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#button-create').prop('disabled', true);
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#button-create').prop('disabled', false);
            },
            success: function(json) {
                if (json['error']) {
                    alert(json['error']);
                }

                if (json['success']) {
                    alert(json['success']);

                    $('#button-refresh').trigger('click');
                }
            },          
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }); 
});

$('#modal-image #button-delete').on('click', function(e) {
    if (confirm('Are You Sure')) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'admin/common/filemanager/delete/',
            type: 'post',       
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                path: $('input[name^=\'path\']:checked'),
                cache: $('input[name^=\'cache\']').val() 
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#button-delete').prop('disabled', true);
            },  
            complete: function() {
                $('#button-delete').prop('disabled', false);
            },      
            success: function(json) {
                if (json['error']) {
                    alert(json['error']);
                }

                if (json['success']) {
                    alert(json['success']);

                    $('#button-refresh').trigger('click');
                }
            },          
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
});
//--></script>
```

Comment: I normally use (hidden=out of viewport) html5 canvas to resize images client side, you save heaps of resources.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an error handler on resize() to see if there's an error that's preventing an image from getting resized:

```
$this->image_lib->clear();        
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);

if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
    echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
}
```

**Update**

It seems the segment is not initialized correctly

```
    $segment = $this->input->get('per_page');
```

Instead try

```
    $segment = $this->input->get('page') * $this->input->get('per_page');
```

Comment: No change still same.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 if you replace `echo` with `exit`, does it halt the script? I'm wondering if the output of `echo` is not visible?

Comment: Still not working. It seems to skip some of the images when I use it on foreach loop. When I click on a button the file manager popup in a modal

Comment: @wolfgang1983 I suspect the issue might be here `($key < $segment && $key >= $segment - $per_page)` - what's the value of `$this->input->get('per_page');`?

Comment: It now resize them but still the image not display on the first lot.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 if `page` is 0 based you'll have to increment it before multiplying

Comment: Sorry no luck will see what else I can do.

Comment: I think I have found solution will do some more testing and then will post answer. +1 for help

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

I have working solution now

I have had to make a check of the directory

```
if (!is_dir(DIR_IMAGE . 'cache/' . $new_image)) {
      if ($this->input->get('directory')) {
         @mkdir(DIR_IMAGE . 'cache/catalog/' . $this->input->get('directory') .'/', 0777, true);
      } else {
         @mkdir(DIR_IMAGE . 'cache/catalog/', 0777, true);
      }
}
```

And also use use a if file exists for resize check and also codeigniter img() helper function helped also.

Full Controller

```
<?php

class Filemanager extends MX_Controller {


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $this->load->library('image_lib');
        $this->load->helper('html');
        define('DIR_IMAGE', FCPATH . 'image/');
        
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['resize_error'] ='';

        $input_get_directory = $this->input->get('directory');
        $input_get_page = $this->input->get('page');
        $input_get_filter = $this->input->get('filter_name');
        $input_get_target = $this->input->get('target');
        $input_get_thumb = $this->input->get('thumb');

        if (isset($input_get_filter)) {
            $filter_name = $input_get_filter;
        } else {
            $filter_name = null;
        }

        // Make sure we have the correct directory
        if (isset($input_get_directory)) {

            $directory = FCPATH . 'image/catalog/' . $input_get_directory;

        } else {

            // Do not add extra tralier slash at end /
            $directory = FCPATH . 'image/catalog';
        }

        if (isset($input_get_page)) {
            $page = $input_get_page;
        } else {
            $page = 1;
        }

        $data['images'] = array();

        // Get directories
        $directories = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);

        if (!$directories) {
            $directories = array();
        }

        // Get files
        $files = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif,JPG,JPEG,PNG,GIF}', GLOB_BRACE);

        if (!$files) {
            $files = array();
        }

        // Merge directories and files
        $images = array_merge($directories, $files);

        // Get total number of files and directories
        $image_total = count($images);

        $per_page = 8;
        $segment = $this->input->get('per_page');
        $segment += $per_page;

        $this->load->model('admin/tool/image_model');
        $this->load->helper('string');

        foreach ($images as $key => $image) {

            if ($key < $segment && $key >= $segment - $per_page) {

                $name = basename(preg_replace("/\.[^.]+$/", "", $image));

                if (is_dir($image)) {

                    $url = '';

                    if (isset($input_get_target)) {
                        $url .= '&target=' . $input_get_target;
                    }

                    if (isset($input_get_thumb)) {
                        $url .= '&thumb=' . $input_get_thumb;
                    }

                    $data['images'][] = array(
                        'thumb' => '',
                        'name' => $name,
                        'href' => '',
                        'type' => 'directory',
                        'path' => substr($image, strlen(FCPATH . 'image/')),
                        'href' => site_url('admin/common/filemanager/?&directory=' . substr($image, strlen(FCPATH . 'image/' . 'catalog/')) . $url)
                    );

                } elseif (is_file($image)) {

                $width = 100;
                $height = 100;

                $old_filename = substr($image, strlen(DIR_IMAGE));

                $extension = pathinfo($old_filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                $new_image = substr($old_filename, 0, strrpos($old_filename, '.')) . '-' . $width . 'x' . $height . '.' . $extension;

                if (!is_dir(DIR_IMAGE . 'cache/' . $new_image)) {
                    if ($this->input->get('directory')) {
                        @mkdir(DIR_IMAGE . 'cache/catalog/' . $this->input->get('directory') .'/', 0777, true);
                    } else {
                        @mkdir(DIR_IMAGE . 'cache/catalog/', 0777, true);
                    }
                }

                if (!file_exists(DIR_IMAGE . 'cache/' . $new_image)) {

                    $config = array(
                        'image_library' => 'gd2',
                        'source_image' => $image,
                        'create_thumb' => false,
                        'maintain_ratio' => false,
                        'width' => $width,
                        'height' => $height,
                        'overwrite' => true,
                        'new_image' => DIR_IMAGE . 'cache/' . $new_image
                    );

                    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);  
                    $this->image_lib->resize();
                    $this->image_lib->clear();
                }

                $data['images'][] = array(
                        'type' => 'image',
                        'href' => '',
                        'thumb' => img('image/cache/'. $new_image),
                        'name' => (strlen($name) > 13) ? substr($name,0,10).'...' : $name,
                        'path' => substr($image, strlen(DIR_IMAGE))
                    );
                }
            }
        }

        $data['heading_title'] = "Image Manager";

        $data['text_no_results'] = "No Results";
        $data['text_confirm'] = "Are You Sure";

        $data['entry_search'] = "Search..";
        $data['entry_folder'] = "New Folder";

        $data['button_parent'] = "Parent";
        $data['button_refresh'] = "Refresh";
        $data['button_upload'] = "Upload";
        $data['button_folder'] = "New Folder";
        $data['button_delete'] = "Delete";
        $data['button_search'] = "Search";

        if (isset($input_get_directory)) {
            $data['directory'] = $input_get_directory;
        } else {
            $data['directory'] = '';
        }

        // Return the filter name
        if (isset($input_get_filter)) {
            $data['filter_name'] = $input_get_filter;
        } else {
            $data['filter_name'] = '';
        }

        // Return the target ID for the file manager to set the value
        if (isset($input_get_target)) {
            $data['target'] = $input_get_target;
        } else {
            $data['target'] = '';
        }

        // Return the thumbnail for the file manager to show a thumbnail
        if (isset($input_get_thumb)) {
            $data['thumb'] = $input_get_thumb;
        } else {
            $data['thumb'] = '';
        }

        // Parent
        $url = '';

        if (isset($input_get_directory)) {
            $pos = strrpos($input_get_directory, '/');

            if ($pos) {
                $url .= '/?&directory=' . substr($input_get_directory, 0, $pos);
            }
        }

        $data['parent'] = site_url('admin/common/filemanager' . $url);

        // Refresh
        $url = '';

        if (isset($input_get_directory)) {
            $url .= '/?&directory=' . $input_get_directory;
        }

        if (isset($input_get_target)) {
            $url .= '&target=' . $input_get_target;
        }

        if (isset($input_get_thumb)) {
            $url .= '&thumb=' . $input_get_thumb;
        }

        $data['refresh'] = site_url('admin/common/filemanager' . $url);

        $url = '';

        if (isset($input_get_directory)) {
            $url .= '?&directory=' . $input_get_directory;
        }

        if (isset($input_get_filter)) {
            $url .= '&filter_name=' . $input_get_filter;
        }

        if (isset($input_get_target)) {
            $url .= '/?&target=' . $input_get_target;
        }

        if (isset($input_get_thumb)) {
            $url .= '&thumb=' . $input_get_thumb;
        }

        $this->load->library('pagination');

        $config['base_url'] = base_url('admin/common/filemanager' . $url);
        $config['total_rows'] = $image_total;
        $config['per_page'] = $per_page;
        $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
        $config['num_links'] = "16";
        $config['full_tag_open'] = "<ul class='pagination'>";
        $config['full_tag_close'] = "</ul>";
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = "<li class='disabled'><li class='active'><a href='#'>";
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = "<span class='sr-only'></span></a></li>";
        $config['next_tag_open'] = "<li>";
        $config['next_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = "<li>";
        $config['prev_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
        $config['first_tag_open'] = "<li>";
        $config['first_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
        $config['last_tag_open'] = "<li>";
        $config['last_tagl_close'] = "</li>";

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

        $this->load->view('common/filemanager_view', $data);
    }

    public function resize($filename) {
        $this->load->library('image_lib');

       //foreach ($filename as $key => $file) {}

        $width = 100;
        $height = 100;

        $old_filename = substr($filename, strlen(FCPATH . 'image/'));

        $extension = pathinfo($old_filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        $new_image = substr($old_filename, 0, strrpos($old_filename, '.')) . '-' . $width . 'x' . $height . '.' . $extension;

        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = $filename;
        $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
        $config['width'] = $width;
        $config['height'] = $height;
        $config['new_image'] = FCPATH . 'image/cache/' . $new_image;
         
        $this->image_lib->clear();        
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
        
        
        if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
            return $this->image_lib->display_errors();
        } else {
            return base_url('image/cache/') . $new_image;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Codeigniter upload library with json and config_item
     */
    public function upload()
    {
        $json = array();

        $input_get_directory = $this->input->get('directory');

        if (isset($input_get_directory)) {
            $directory = 'image/catalog/' . $input_get_directory;
        } else {
            $directory = 'image/catalog';
        }

        $config['upload_path'] = './' . $directory . '/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = 5000;
        $config['max_width'] = '0';
        $config['max_height'] = '0';
        $config['overwrite'] = FALSE;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        $input_name = "file";

        if ($this->upload->do_upload($input_name) == FALSE) {
            $json['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
        } else {
            $file_data = $this->upload->data();
            $json['success'] = "This file" . ' ' . $file_data['file_name'] . ' ' . "has been uploaded";
        }

        $this->output->set_content_type('Content-Type: application/json');
        $this->output->set_output(json_encode($json));
    }

    public function folder()
    {
        $json = array();

        $input_get_directory = $this->input->get('directory');

        // Make sure we have the correct directory
        if (isset($input_get_directory)) {

            $directory = FCPATH . 'image/catalog/' . $input_get_directory;

        } else {

            // Do not add extra tralier slash at end /
            $directory = FCPATH . 'image/catalog';
        }

        // Check its a directory
        if (!is_dir($directory)) {
            $json['error'] = $this->lang->line('error_directory');
        }

        if (!$json) {

            $input_get_folder = $this->input->post('folder');

            // Sanitize the folder name
            $folder = str_replace(array('../', '..\\', '..'), '', basename(html_entity_decode($input_get_folder, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')));

            // Validate the filename length
            if ((utf8_strlen($folder) < 3) || (utf8_strlen($folder) > 128)) {
                $json['error'] = $this->lang->line('error_folder');
            }

            // Check if directory already exists or not
            if (is_dir($directory . '/' . $folder)) {
                $json['error'] = $this->lang->line('error_exists');
            }
        }

        if (!$json) {
            mkdir($directory . '/' . $folder, 0777);

            $json['success'] = $this->lang->line('text_directory');
        }


        $this->output->set_content_type('Content-Type: application/json');
        $this->output->set_output(json_encode($json));
    }

    public function delete()
    {
        $json = array();

        $input_path_post = $this->input->post('path');

        if (isset($input_path_post)) {
            $paths = $input_path_post;
        } else {
            $paths = array();
        }

        // Loop through each path to run validations
        foreach ($paths as $path) {
            $path = rtrim(FCPATH . 'image/' . str_replace(array('../', '..\\', '..'), '', $path), '/');

            // Check path exsists
            if ($path == FCPATH . 'image/' . 'catalog') {
                $json['error'] = $this->lang->line('error_delete');

                break;
            }
        }

        if (!$json) {
            // Loop through each path
            foreach ($paths as $path) {
                $path = rtrim(FCPATH . 'image/' . str_replace(array('../', '..\\', '..'), '', $path), '/');

                // If path is just a file delete it
                if (is_file($path)) {
                    unlink($path);

                    // If path is a directory beging deleting each file and sub folder
                } elseif (is_dir($path)) {
                    $files = array();

                    // Make path into an array
                    $path = array($path . '*');

                    // While the path array is still populated keep looping through
                    while (count($path) != 0) {
                        $next = array_shift($path);

                        foreach (glob($next) as $file) {
                            // If directory add to path array
                            if (is_dir($file)) {
                                $path[] = $file . '/*';
                            }

                            // Add the file to the files to be deleted array
                            $files[] = $file;
                        }
                    }

                    // Reverse sort the file array
                    rsort($files);

                    foreach ($files as $file) {
                        // If file just delete
                        if (is_file($file)) {
                            unlink($file);

                            // If directory use the remove directory function
                        } elseif (is_dir($file)) {
                            rmdir($file);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            $json['success'] = $this->lang->line('text_delete');
        }

        $this->output->set_content_type('Content-Type: application/json');
        $this->output->set_output(json_encode($json));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very very wrong: `if ($this->input->get('directory')) {` *Never trust user input*. Someone could make script to make thousands and thousands empty directories and block your server. You must not allow user to have this kind of ability.

Comment: @Tpojka show examples what you would think is best then

Comment: Best is not allow user have ability for something like `https://example.com/filemanager/upload?directory=what_ever_i_want` This is manually built primer, but malicious code could be implemented to make cURL request from external server and fill your server with rubbish directories. You need to provide some extra security to disallow that. You have to be very careful who and when is able to use this method. Other than that I don't know your project/business logic to tell more. Just offering 2c advise of what should you be aware of. I didn't check question, just saw this security hole though.

Comment: I don't under stand curl

Comment: @Tpojka what about using codeigniter uri segments instead ?

Comment: Start [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), [here](https://curl.haxx.se/) or somewhat like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=curl+posting+to+website). My point is that your code mustn't allow that anyone who passes some URL like one in my previous comment, can create directory. Never allow that freedom to clients.

Comment: Most simplest way you can do is limiting directory creation on every 5 seconds (at least) from same client. Even that way, script would be able to create almost 20.000 directories per day. It is not up to checking what is in URL, it is not allowing that logic to unknown clients. You have to set some security check and/or limitation with session or (jw)token etc.

Comment: I voted down since this code snippet has that amount of security vulnerability that mustn't be offered to freshers or anyone who is trying to learn PHP. **Freshers DON'T TRUST user input or variables passed from client. Period.**

Comment: It is done by ajax and the file manager pops up in a model though. Users can not directly accesses the controller

Comment: You can not prevent it that way. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931499/security-in-ajax-how-to-prevent-curl-to-post-data#answer-5931529) is nice answer. You can't prevent because your server accept someone's browser or some other server terminal in same way. For your server they are _clients_. Test it on your own: type in terminal `curl https://stackoverflow.com/` and you'll see response from server. Same way you can test your own URLs. Also, you can test it from [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).